# Comparison of Lexica: BDB and Strong's Hebrew

Tags: hebrew, jewish-books, dictionary

Which has more entries, BDB or Strong's Hebrew?

Is there any known mapping between the two?

Comment: I found a mapping here, e.g. http://concordances.org/hebrew/543.htm

Comment: Also, the first sentence here seems to indicate that the BDB's entries are at least an improper subset of Strong's: http://www.bible-discovery.com/dictionary-license-bdb.php

Comment: Walrus the Cat, welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy it. Your question would be more valuable if it would include some (brief) background info on what _BDB_ and _Strong's_ are, perhaps linking to Wikipedia or somewhere, that explains why you thought of the possible existence of a mapping. Also, if you discovered an answer to your question within ten minutes of asking it by Googling (as it seems), then the question is rather weak; but the answer might be good: why not write it up as an answer, below?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but the BDB Dictionary usually comes with numbers linking the root words to the individual entries in the Strong Concordance. In terms of sheer quantity of entries, I'd guess that the Strong has more but that's only because BDB only lists words by root once and then includes all forms of that word under that one listing. If that's not what you mean, you'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: @Shemmy good point.

Comment: @msh210 I'd expect people who are this into this subject matter to know what these very ubiquitous reference materials are.  If they don't, they are free to not answer my question.  My Google-fu has nothing to do with the weakness of my question, and I'd like someone who knows more about this than me to chime in.

Comment: @WalrustheCat Welcome to the site! While your point is valid, in this community we often encourage people to dejargonify so that even if someone doesn't know the answer and isn't familiar with the territory, they may find the Q and A interesting. There's a lot of fancy lingo that gets thrown around here, believe me, but we try to make it so that everyone can understand. :D

Comment: @HodofHod that's a good point.  I'll try to keep that in mind, thank you.

Comment: @WalrustheCat for the record, I'm not sure to what extent either of these resources are used by traditional Jews.  I was under the impression that they were mainly used for academic and secular studies, and by adherents of other religions.  I could be wrong.

Comment: @yoel, are there better lexicons out there that I don't know about?

Comment: @WalrustheCat I don't know if use by the yeshiva world *necessarily* means better, especially depending on one's goals in learning, but in my experience [Jastrow](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/jastrow/) is by far the most utilized academic resource.

Comment: @yoel There are lots of great books and resources that are underappreciated by traditional Jews and/or academics alike.

Comment: @DoubleAA for sure - I was just trying to get across that this forum might not be able to give Walrus the best answer possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm going to answer it myself, based on the comments above.

1. Mapping

1 Strongs entry -> possibly multiple BDB entries

Apparently, because Hebrew words can be browsed by Strong's entry at concordances.org/hebrew, and each entry is linked to a BDB entry, then there is at most 1 BDB entry per Strong's entry, and the two are mapped (from Strongs to BDB) at that URL.

1. Number of Entries

Strongs > BDB

Shemmy's reasoning seems good.  Strong's is exhaustive.  I believe BDB is also exhaustive, but it is organized by one entry per tri-radical root.  Being that Strong's contains multiple entries per root, and BDB contains only one entry (containing multiple instances of that root in the text), Strong's is bound to have more entries.

Comment: Just reading this, it doesn't make any sense.  How can there be more Strongs entries, yet each maps to possibly multiple BDB entries?  Does redundancy account for this apparent discrepancy?

Comment: @Warlus the Cat, if you think this doesn't answer the question, you might want to remove "accepted" mark from this answer, in order to avoid confusion of occasional googlers

Comment: Thanks, but I do think it answers the question.  Redundancy can, and probably does account for the oddity.

Comment: Of course, I'm open opinions on that.